# Facebook and php - getting user's name

Tags: php, facebook

How can I get this user's name using his/hers `uid` in my app using `php`? I'm assuming that the given user permitted my app to access this data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook has [php-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/) (a convenient php library that can be used to use facebook api)  that has exactly this example, [a source](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) available for you.

Answer (score 0):

use php-sdk library to get user information.

$facebook->api('/me') returns all information regarding user(name,email etc)